# JDK 7 fork/join simple example

Tags: java, java-7, fork-join

Can someone provide a simple example of fork/join feature in JDK 7.

I looked at the example provided by Oracle and it is bit confusing

Comment: There are many search engines where you can find the examples..... I searched in Google for "fork and join example, java 7" an dgot alot of examples....

Comment: *"example provided by Oracle .. is bit confusing"*  If Oracle cannot explain it to you, what makes you think we can?  Especially when you neither link to the example, nor tell us what about it you do not understand.  All in all, a poorly researched and expressed question.

Comment: A better question would most likely be to ask specifics about what you don't understand from Oracle's example.  I personally was looking at their example a couple weeks ago, and I found it to be extremely clear.

Comment: What i mean is, Oracle haven't provided a example which I can copy and paste in my notepad and run (a working example). I always find the approach of running a sample program first and then going through the theory much easier.

Comment: as to poor examples from suppliers: that's nothing new. Though Sun/Oracle aren't as bad as say IBM, they do have their moments :)

Answer (score 3):

use the following link:-

http://rashidnoorani.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-use-fork-join-framework-features.html

http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/using-jdk-7s-forkjoin-framework/231000556

Comment: The poster asked for alternative examples to the Oracle-provided one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is oracle Docs : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Performance : http://www.developer.com/java/java-7-forkjoin-framework.html

Also, you can search `fork and join  java 7` in Google.